# Reactivity not working inside the loop for unknown reason in vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm struggling to get working the reactivity in vue.js inside the loop. Loop is rendering without any issue, But, when trying to fire an event it updates the content but not visible or render data in the page.

I've used the latest version of vue.js with bootstrap and jquery. I've tried adding `key` in the loop item but not working. But, when to update any other content by using `v-model` then it works.

**Markup**

```html
<div id="app">

  <div class="props">
    <div class="prop-item" v-for="prop in modules.variations.properties">
      <p>=== <strong v-text="prop.name"></strong> ===</p>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="value in prop.values" @click="activeProp(prop,value)">
          <span v-text="value.name"></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="text" v-model="message">

<pre>{{ actives }}</pre>
<pre>{{ message }}</pre>
</div>

<script>
window.spdata = {
   "variations":{
      "properties":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Color",
            "values":[
               {
                  "id":1,
                  "name":"Black",
               },
               {
                  "id":2,
                  "name":"Red",
               },
               {
                  "id":3,
                  "name":"Blue",
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"Size",
            "values":[
               {
                  "id":4,
                  "name":"XL",
               },
               {
                  "id":5,
                  "name":"XXL",
               },
               {
                  "id":6,
                  "name":"XXXL",
               },
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "name": "Type",
            "values":[
               {
                  "id":8,
                  "name":"Premium",
               },
               {
                  "id":9,
                  "name":"Standard",
               },
               {
                  "id":10,
                  "name":"Luxary",
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
};
</script>
```

**Javascript**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    modules: window.spdata,
    actives: {},
    message: '',
  },

  created() {
    this.modules.variations.properties.forEach((prop) => {
      this.actives[prop.id] = null
    });
  },

  methods: {
    activeProp(prop, val) {
      if (this.actives[prop.id] === val.id) {
        this.actives[prop.id] = null;
      } else {
        this.actives[prop.id] = val.id;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Vue will not notice you changing members of `this.actives`. [Change detection caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Comment: @RoyJ Yes, that true. I've used `Vue.$set()` but forget to use in the created section and that is the issue. Thank you for notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to be using `Vue.set()` to update an array inside your `methods` block, not the square bracket syntax. You should also provide a `:key` for elements inside your `v-for` loop. This is good hygiene whenever dealing with loops and arrays.

Comment: Great! Just solved. I did forget to use `Vue.$set()` in one place and that place kills my day.

Thank you so much.